# Why is the training loss constantly increasing?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification

The following text is the result of translation by the translator, I am sorry if there are grammatical errors. Please bear with me, and please also ignore the Chinese comments in the code.
I am new to deep learning. I have just finished learning multi-layer perceptrons, and I have just started learning CNN, and I haven't finished it yet. In the past two days, I found a third-party image classification dataset (I searched it in advance because I will use it later in the paper), and implemented a simple CNN network. Although the code can run through, there is a serious problem, that is, the loss has increased since the beginning of the training, and the accuracy of the final test is relatively low but not ridiculously low. The specific data sets and codes are as follows:
The data set is a [Lung Nodule Malignancy](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kmader/lungnodemalignancy?resource=download) recognition data set, a binary classification data set, containing 6691 pieces of data, and the size is [1, 64, 64]. I divide it into a training set and a test set according to 8:2.
The code show as below:

```
# 导入所需的库
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import h5py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, random_split

# 定义超参数
num_epochs = 5
batch_size = 100
learning_rate = 0.0001

# 使用GPU
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

```
# 加载MNIST数据集并进行预处理
# 定义Dataset类
class HDF5Dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, file_path, transform=None):
        # file_path: hdf5文件的路径
        # transform: 可选的图像变换操作
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.transform = transform
        # 打开hdf5文件（只读模式）
        self.hdf5_file = h5py.File(file_path, "r")
        # 获取图像和标签的数据集对象（注意修改为实际名称）
        self.images = self.hdf5_file["ct_slices"]
        self.labels = self.hdf5_file["new_slice_class"]

    def __len__(self):
        # 返回数据集的大小
        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # 根据索引返回一张图片及其标签
        image = self.images[index] # 从hdf5文件中读取图像数据
        label = self.labels[index] # 从hdf5文件中读取标签数据

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        return image, label
    
# 定义图像变换操作
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(), # 将图片转换为张量格式
])

# 创建数据集对象
dataset = HDF5Dataset(file_path="all_patches.hdf5", transform=transform)

# 定义训练集和测试集的大小（8:2）
train_size = int(0.8 * len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size

# 随机分割数据集为训练集和测试集
train_dataset, test_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, test_size])

# 创建训练集和测试集的数据加载器对象
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=32, drop_last=True)

# 使用for循环遍历训练集和测试集
print("Training set:")
print(f"Train dataset size: {len(train_dataset)}")
for images, labels in train_loader:
    print(images.shape) 
    print(labels.shape)
    # print(images) 
    # print(labels)
    break
print("------------------------------------------------")

print("Test set:")
print(f"Test dataset size: {len(test_dataset)}")
for images, labels in test_loader:
    print(images.shape) 
    print(labels.shape)
    # print(images) 
    # print(labels)
    break
print("------------------------------------------------")
```

```
# 定义网络
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        # 定义卷积层，输入通道为1，输出通道为16，卷积核大小为5，步长为1，填充为1
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3, 1, 1)
        # 定义激活函数，使用ReLU函数
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        # 定义池化层，使用最大池化，池化核大小为2，步长为2
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # 定义卷积层，输入通道为16，输出通道为32，卷积核大小为5，步长为1，填充为1
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, 1, 1)
        # 定义激活函数，使用ReLU函数
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        # 定义池化层，使用最大池化，池化核大小为2，步长为2
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # 定义全连接层，输入特征数为32*16*16
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*16*16, 1024)
        # 定义激活函数，使用ReLU函数
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        # 定义全连接层，输入特征数为1024，输出为128
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 128)
        # 定义激活函数，使用ReLU函数
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        # 定义全连接层，128，输出为128，输出特征数为2
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128, 2)
        # 定义softmax操作
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        # 前向传播过程
        #包括
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 32 * 16 * 16)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu4(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x
```

```
# 创建一个CNN对象，并将其移动到GPU上
net = CNN().to(device)

# 创建损失函数和优化器，并指定要优化的参数和学习率
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

```
# 训练CNN网络
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, (data, label) in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        # 将数据和标签移动到GPU上
        data, label = data.to(device), label.to(device, dtype=torch.int64)

        # 梯度清零
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # 前向传播、计算损失、反向传播和优化
        output = net(data)
        loss = criterion(output, label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # 计算损失和准确率
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if (i+1) % 10 == 0:    # 每10个batch输出一次
            current_running_loss = running_loss / 10
            print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1} Batch {i+1}, Loss: {current_running_loss:.4f}")

print('Finished Training')
```

```
# 在测试集上评估CNN网络的性能
correct = 0
total = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for data, label in test_loader:
        # 将输入和标签移到GPU上
        data, label = data.to(device), label.to(device)

        # 前向传播、计算预测结果和准确率
        outputs = net(data)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += label.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == label).sum().item()
    
    print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: {} %'.format(100 * correct / total))
```

The output of the model training part is as follows:

```
Epoch 1 Batch 10, Loss: 0.6785
Epoch 1 Batch 20, Loss: 1.3699
Epoch 1 Batch 30, Loss: 2.0675
Epoch 1 Batch 40, Loss: 2.7401
Epoch 1 Batch 50, Loss: 3.4534
Epoch 1 Batch 60, Loss: 4.1604
Epoch 1 Batch 70, Loss: 4.8768
Epoch 1 Batch 80, Loss: 5.5619
Epoch 1 Batch 90, Loss: 6.2502
Epoch 1 Batch 100, Loss: 6.9353
Epoch 1 Batch 110, Loss: 7.6517
Epoch 1 Batch 120, Loss: 8.3900
Epoch 1 Batch 130, Loss: 9.0907
Epoch 1 Batch 140, Loss: 9.7634
Epoch 1 Batch 150, Loss: 10.4548
Epoch 1 Batch 160, Loss: 11.1305
Epoch 2 Batch 10, Loss: 0.6695
Epoch 2 Batch 20, Loss: 1.3921
Epoch 2 Batch 30, Loss: 2.0835
Epoch 2 Batch 40, Loss: 2.8093
Epoch 2 Batch 50, Loss: 3.5194
Epoch 2 Batch 60, Loss: 4.2608
Epoch 2 Batch 70, Loss: 4.9428
Epoch 2 Batch 80, Loss: 5.6123
Epoch 2 Batch 90, Loss: 6.3225
Epoch 2 Batch 100, Loss: 6.9889
Epoch 2 Batch 110, Loss: 7.6459
Epoch 2 Batch 120, Loss: 8.3060
Epoch 2 Batch 130, Loss: 8.9630
Epoch 2 Batch 140, Loss: 9.6919
Epoch 2 Batch 150, Loss: 10.3833
Epoch 2 Batch 160, Loss: 11.0528
Epoch 3 Batch 10, Loss: 0.6851
Epoch 3 Batch 20, Loss: 1.3828
Epoch 3 Batch 30, Loss: 2.0960
Epoch 3 Batch 40, Loss: 2.8062
Epoch 3 Batch 50, Loss: 3.5101
Epoch 3 Batch 60, Loss: 4.1358
Epoch 3 Batch 70, Loss: 4.8366
Epoch 3 Batch 80, Loss: 5.5280
Epoch 3 Batch 90, Loss: 6.1600
Epoch 3 Batch 100, Loss: 6.8732
Epoch 3 Batch 110, Loss: 7.6021
Epoch 3 Batch 120, Loss: 8.2810
Epoch 3 Batch 130, Loss: 8.9693
Epoch 3 Batch 140, Loss: 9.6669
Epoch 3 Batch 150, Loss: 10.3552
Epoch 3 Batch 160, Loss: 11.0528
Epoch 4 Batch 10, Loss: 0.6633
Epoch 4 Batch 20, Loss: 1.3921
Epoch 4 Batch 30, Loss: 2.1117
Epoch 4 Batch 40, Loss: 2.8155
Epoch 4 Batch 50, Loss: 3.5226
Epoch 4 Batch 60, Loss: 4.1858
Epoch 4 Batch 70, Loss: 4.8803
Epoch 4 Batch 80, Loss: 5.6092
Epoch 4 Batch 90, Loss: 6.2850
Epoch 4 Batch 100, Loss: 6.9732
Epoch 4 Batch 110, Loss: 7.7209
Epoch 4 Batch 120, Loss: 8.3904
Epoch 4 Batch 130, Loss: 9.0505
Epoch 4 Batch 140, Loss: 9.7357
Epoch 4 Batch 150, Loss: 10.4271
Epoch 4 Batch 160, Loss: 11.0809
Epoch 5 Batch 10, Loss: 0.6758
Epoch 5 Batch 20, Loss: 1.3546
Epoch 5 Batch 30, Loss: 2.0179
Epoch 5 Batch 40, Loss: 2.7468
Epoch 5 Batch 50, Loss: 3.4819
Epoch 5 Batch 60, Loss: 4.1858
Epoch 5 Batch 70, Loss: 4.8866
Epoch 5 Batch 80, Loss: 5.5967
Epoch 5 Batch 90, Loss: 6.2319
Epoch 5 Batch 100, Loss: 6.9045
Epoch 5 Batch 110, Loss: 7.6021
Epoch 5 Batch 120, Loss: 8.2841
Epoch 5 Batch 130, Loss: 8.9474
Epoch 5 Batch 140, Loss: 9.6763
Epoch 5 Batch 150, Loss: 10.3677
Epoch 5 Batch 160, Loss: 11.0528
Finished Training
```

One way I know of to address this problem is to turn down the learning rate, but it doesn't improve. I would like to know if the seniors can advise me how to optimize and solve this problem in this case.
Because I am a pure novice, I will definitely make some mistakes that may be very stupid. Just do not hesitate to enlighten me, and please don't blame me too much, thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: You are accumulating loss over batches on a variable and printing that variable, of course it increases, you should take the mean or something like that.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Ok, I see what the problem is, I made a very low level mistake, I kept tweaking the parameters and neglected to check the basic control statement. : ( Thank you for your help. : )